# Converting a column containing string time format into minutes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time

I contain a time data frame that has time in this format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': ['20hours 10minutes', '18hours 10minutes',
                            '15minutes', '1minutes']})
                Time
0  20hours 10minutes
1  18hours 10minutes
2          15minutes
3           1minutes
```

I would like to convert the entire column into minutes. Any suggestions?
My problem is that later on, it is just minutes left and no hours, so whatever I try I can't get it right

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`pd.to_timedelta()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) to parse the time strings and use [`pd.Timedelta.total_seconds()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.total_seconds.html) to get the total seconds for conversion to minutes, as follows:

```
df['minutes'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time']).dt.total_seconds() / 60
```

Result:

```
                Time  minutes
0  20hours 10minutes   1210.0
1  18hours 10minutes   1090.0
2          15minutes     15.0
3           1minutes      1.0
```

Comment: Wow, that is a really simple solution.  Nicely done, I was scratching my head on this one